# sql - removing rows having a two same column value

Tags: sql, union

table 1

```
|-------------------------------|
| empid   |  scheddate| schedule|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-21 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-22 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-23 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-24 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-25 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-26 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
```

table2

```
|-------------------------------|
| empid   |  scheddate| schedule|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
```

using

```
insert into table3 
select * from table1 union select * from table2
```

i've got

table 3

```
|-------------------------------|
| empid   |  scheddate| schedule|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-21 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-22 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-23 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-24 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-25 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-26 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
```

i want to know how to have a result like this

```
|-------------------------------|
| empid   |  scheddate| schedule|
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-24 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-25 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-26 |  null   |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   1     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-21 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-22 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
|   2     |2017-04-23 |  8-5    |
|-------------------------------|
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create `table 3` in this form or how to generate output based on `table 3` (or `table 1` and `table 2`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want this logic:

```
insert into table3 (empid, scheddate, schedule) -- should always list columns 
    select empid, scheddate, schedule
    from table1 t1 
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.empid = t1.empid and t2.scheddate = t1.scheddate)
    union all
    select empid, scheddate, schedule
    from table2;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank You Very Much. how can I upvote your answer ? newbie here

Comment: @MarvindeGuzman You can't upvote just yet, but you can ACCEPT Gordon's answer by clicking on the checkmark which is just below the downvote icon.

Comment: @MarvindeGuzman No, only one.  Not the first time I lost the vote to Gordon.   :)